# How to stop wordpress to make the default query?

Tags: wp-query, url-rewriting, templates

My goal is a redirect to a custom template based on some new rewrite rule, but without having wordpress to make unusefull queries.

my code:

```
function add_rewrite_rules() {

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^settore/([^/]*)/?$',
        'index.php?settore=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );

  add_rewrite_tag('%settore%','(caldareria|tessile)');
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_rewrite_rules' );

function set_root_category_template($template){
    $settore = get_query_var('settore');
    if($settore != '') $template = locate_template('root-taxonomy.php');
    return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include','set_root_category_template',99);
```

It redirects just right, but if I check $wp_query->posts in root-taxonomy.php, I see a list of regular post. Instead, in that page I'll make a custom query asking for some specific taxonomy terms data, and therefore, the default query is totally useless. How can I stop it? After all, I'm not passing any default query var to index.php so I can't understand the reason why wp is still doing a query..

Comment: template_redirect hook instead of template_include would be a good start

Comment: but docs say that it's not a good idea for loading different templates [http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect]

Comment: If you are still doing something reasonably conventional (querying posts) you should adjust main query instead of discarding it. Getting rid of it completely is impractical and messy.

Comment: when both `template_include` and `template_redirect` are fired main query already happen, so using any of the two hooks you can't stop it.

Comment: @Rarst "impractical" is probably a good definition for my answer :D

Comment: @G.M. considering the fact that was about redirect and `template_include` is for includes to my knowledge. But you're right that would not solve the issue here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stop WordPress to run main query is hard: you have to dig inside the deep heart of WordPress.

WordPress frontend workflow:

1. [`wp-blog-header.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-blog-header.php) call the function `wp()`
2. [`wp()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/functions.php#L824) function creates an instance of [wp class](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp.php), and call `main()` method on it
3. [`main()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L608) method code:

   ```
   public function main($query_args = '') {
     $this->init();
     $this->parse_request($query_args); // build query vars starting from url
     $this->send_headers();
     $this->query_posts();  // run main query via WP_Query using built query vars
     $this->handle_404(); // if query has no results set 404 headers and WP_Query props
     $this->register_globals();
   }
   ```
4. `wp-blog-header.php` include [`template-loader.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/template-loader.php) that load template file based on query

So only way to stop main query is prevent `wp()` to run.

That can be done hooking an early hook, do what you need, and finally `exit()`.

The problem of this approach is that preventing `wp()` to run, you also prevent wp class to parse request, so the rewrite stuff you add are not parsed.

So, instead of to add a rewrite tag and a rewrite rule, you may want to look straight at the **url** to choose if it is the one that should trigger your custom action.

First of all let's write a function that return only the relative parte of the url, e.g. if current url is something like `example.com/wp/path/to/somewhere?foo=bar` and your home url is `example.com/wp/` the function returns `path/to/somewhere` :

```
function get_relative_url() {
  $home_path = rtrim( parse_url( home_url(), PHP_URL_PATH ), '/' );
  $path = trim( substr( add_query_arg( array() ), strlen( $home_path ) ), '/' );
  $qs = array_keys( $_GET );
  if ( ! empty( $qs ) ) {
    $path = remove_query_arg( $qs, $path );
  }
  return $path;
}
```

Now we can use an early hook to look at the url, and only if it contains the desired path we'll set the `$settore` variable, load the template and exit:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', function() { // 'wp_loaded' hook happen before wp() is ran

  $path = get_relative_url();
  $url_parts = explode( '/', $path );
  if (
    isset( $url_parts[1] )
    && $url_parts[0] === 'settore'
    && in_array( $url_parts[1], array( 'caldareria', 'tessile' ), TRUE )
  ) {
    // ok the current url is something like example.com/settore/tessile
    // and 'tessile' is in the variable $url_parts[1]
    $template = locate_template( 'root-taxonomy.php' );
    if ( empty( $template ) ) return; // do nothing if template not found
    global $settore;
    $settore = $url_parts[1]; // in the template you can access to $settore variable.
    require_once $template;
    exit(); // prevent WordPress to do anything else
  }

} );
```

That's all.

In code above, understanding if the current url is the *right one*, and set the `$settore` variable was easy because the url structure was easy, for more complex url structures, you probably need a regex matching, and maybe use a tool like [Symfony routing component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html) to match the url to some variables.

This approach is the one I've used in [Cortex](http://cortex.zoomlab.it), have a look there if you plan to commonly do thing like that.

### Gotchas

as you can see, the main query (`global $wp_query`) in code I posted is not used, in your template it will be an empty `WP_Query` object, so anything will refer to main query, e.g. template tags like `is_tax()`, `is_archive()` or such, will not work.

That will apply to header and footer as well, because very probably in your 'root-taxonomy.php' you'll use `get_header()` and `get_footer()`.

Also some plugins may not work properly, e.g. if you are using any SEO plugin that set title tag based on the query, than it will have issues.

A possible solution is to manually set main query properties accessing to `global $wp_query` or use a custom header, e.g. `get_header('root-tax')`, for your custom template and handle in `header-root-tax.php` custom title tag and/or any other issue.

Comment: Yes this can be usefull, thank you! And great job with [the Brain project](http://giuseppe-mazzapica.github.io/Brain/)!

Comment: P.s. you should show your project to [this scientist](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonio_Damasio) ;)

Comment: @Stratboy yep, or maybe to [him](http://www.brainforum.it/giancarlo-comi/) :)

Answer (score 1):

why not like this?

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_queries' );
function my_post_queries( $query ) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() && !is_admin()) {
        // maybe check for specific page here
        // if (is_tax('your-taxonomy') { 
        $query = false;
        remove_all_actions ( '__after_loop');
        // }
    }
}
```

Or did I misunderstand the question?